# Different classes always have a sing instance for a common property

Tags: php, oop, object, design-patterns

Let's take the manufacturer/car model example. A model has a specific manufacturer. So let's say the models "Punto", "500", "Panda" have always the manufacturer "Fiat".

If the models are one class each and the manufacturer is a class instance what's the cleanest/best solution to get the models connected to a manufacturer without having multiple instances of the manufacturer class. Setting them via constructor is obvious because a model can never change from who it gets manufactured.

Let's show my problem in a simplified code sample:

```
class Manufacturer
{
    protected $name;

    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}

abstract class Car
{
    protected $manufacturer;

    public function __construct(Manufacturer $manufacturer)
    {
        $this->manufacturer = $manufacturer;
    }

    abstract public function getModel();

    public function getManufacturer()
    {
        return $this->manufacturer;
    }
}

class ModelA extends Car
{
    public function getModel()
    {
        return 'A';
    }
}

class ModelB extends Car
{
    public function getModel()
    {
        return 'B';
    }
}

// The manufacturer instance
$manufacturerC = new Manufacturer('C');

// Setting the manufacturer for the models is obvious
// because they always get manufactured from the manufacturer "C"
// and never from a manufacturer "X"
$modelA = new ModelA($manufacturerC);
$modelB = new ModelB($manufacturerC);
```

Comment: I would pass a reference to the instance using &

Comment: @RonDadon that's how my example code works. But setting the reference of the manufacturer for the models is obvious because it will always be the same.

Comment: If you use reference, than change in the manufactor will reflect in all the model that depends on it. The way you pass it, is passing a copy of the instance, so changes in instance itself will not reflect in the "cars".

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I could come up with its the following:

The models hold the class name of the manufacturer. This way I can get the manufacturer instance from a `ManufacturerPool` which holds an instance of all manufacturers.

```
abstract class Manufacturer
{
    protected $name;

    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}

class ManufacturerC extends Manufacturer
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct('C');
    }
}

abstract class Car
{
    abstract public function getModel();

    abstract public function getManufacturer();
}

class ModelA extends Car
{
    public function getModel()
    {
        return 'A';
    }

    public function getManufacturer()
    {
        return C::class;
    }
}

class ModelB extends Car
{
    public function getModel()
    {
        return 'B';
    }

    public function getManufacturer()
    {
        return C::class;
    }
}

// The manufacturer instance
$manufacturerPool = new ManufacturerPool();
$manufacturerPool->add(new ManufacturerC());

$modelA = new ModelA();
$modelB = new ModelB();

$manufacturerPool->get($modelA->getManufacturer()); // Returns instance of "C"
$manufacturerPool->get($modelB->getManufacturer()); // Returns instance of "C"
```

The disadvantage of this solution is that each manufacturer has to be an own class.